# Finding the point where the angle of incidence is equal to the angle of reflection

Tags: geometry

Say I have two points, $$A=(-1,1)\\B=(2,1)$$ and a line at $$y=0$$ How do I find the point on the line that makes A and B have the same angle?

Comment: Find reflection points $A', B'$ across the line $y=0$.  Then the lines $A'B, AB'$ intersect on the line $y = 0$ at the point in question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In order to have the same angle it is enough to have

$$PD=PC=\frac{3}{2}\to 2-x=\frac{3}{2}\to x=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @script8man: Is it clear?